# Unity 2020.2.1f1 markerless AR plugins

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, augmented-reality, kudan, 8thwall-xr

I'm trying to create an application with AR, using surface detection plugins that work with all devices no matter of ARcore installed.
Well, I have got a problem, 8th wall works terrible in unity, EasyAR shows a black screen instead of camera image when I'm trying to use surface detection (but EasyAR image target detection works fine), Kudan, finally, don't work at all, it just shows a black screen on my phone.

Does someone know some other AR plugins, which can detect surface without ARCore like 8th wall web?
Or maybe how to solve the 8th wall in unity, how to force it to work like web 8th wall?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Vuforia Engine plugin. Their latest version provides spatial augmented reality. It requires 3d scanner. You can get more information about this in their developer portal. I hope this is what you are looking for.